Support of a Baire measure
Given a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$, a Baire measure $\mu$ on $X$, and its support:
$$\text{supp} \ \mu = \left( \bigcup \{ O \subseteq X : O \ \text{is open}, \mu (O) = 0 \} \right)^c$$
I want to show several properties of this support/measure (for instance, if $O$ is an open Baire set s.t. $O \cap \text{supp} \ \mu \neq \emptyset$ then $\mu (O) > 0$). 
My main issue is understanding how to work with Baire measures/sets. I know the definition of both of them, but I don't understand how to effectively use them, or what properties I can derive from them. 
Moreover, is $\text{supp} \ \mu$ a Baire set? 
Thank you to all who can help.

Which definition of Baire set are you using? They're not all equivalent.

Right, I should have added that I'm using Halmos's definition, i.e., an element of the smallest $\sigma$-Algebra containing all compact $G_\delta$ sets.

For the first question, this is true just applying the definition. Indeed, if $O$ is open Baire and $\mu(O) = 0$, then it is in the union defining $\mathrm{supp}\,\mu$, so it is in the complement of $\mathrm{supp}\,\mu$, i.e., $O \cap \mathrm{supp}\,\mu = \varnothing$.
For the “moreover” question, no. $\mathrm{supp}\,\mu$ is always closed, but may not be Baire. For example, let $X = [0, 1]^\kappa$ with an uncountable cardinal $\kappa$ and let $\mu$ be the Dirac delta measure at a given point $x \in X$. One may then verify that $\mathrm{supp}\,\mu = \{x\}$ but no singleton is Baire in $X$.

Is $O$ in the complement of $\text{supp} \mu$ as an element or as a subset?
Moreover, what do you think will be the case if we replace $O$ with a compact Baire set?

@CauchyChaos As a subset. The complement of $\mathrm{supp},\mu$ is a union of sets, one of which is $O$, so $O \subset (\mathrm{supp},\mu)^c$. For the second question, do you mean that if $O$ is a compact Baire set s.t. $O \cap \mathrm{supp},\mu \neq \varnothing$, then whether $\mu(O) > 0$? If that is the question, then no. You can just choose a Baire measure of full support (say, the Lebesgue measure on $[0, 1]$) and any nonempty compact Baire set with zero measure (say, a singleton in $[0, 1]$).
